# How to dynamically configure FusionCharts to render linked charts without using eval

Tags: javascript, eval, fusioncharts

Is there a way to dynamically configure FusionCharts to render linked charts without using eval?  I got [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j49phLzL/3/) from FusionCharts support this morning where they showed me how to use the `configureLink` method (at the bottom of the jsFiddle):

```
chart1.configureLink({
    id:'chart1',
    type: 'column3d'
});
```

Note however the reference to `chart1` and it's use as the id - these are both essentially hard-coded at the top of the jsFiddle: `var chart1 = new FusionCharts({...`

We are generating our charts dynamically however, and we don't know how many on a given page, so we are doing them inside a loop as follows:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var fusionChartsCfg = JSON.parse(chartJson); //chartJson defined above

    for (var i=0, n=fusionChartsCfg.length; i<n; i++) {
        var chartConfig = fusionChartsCfg[i];
        new FusionCharts(chartConfig).render();

        /*
        eval('var fChart = chart' + i + '=new FusionCharts(chartConfig)');
        fChart.render();

        if (chartConfig.linkedChartType) {
            fChart.configureLink({
                id:'chart' + i,
                type: chartConfig.linkedChartType
            });
        }
        */          
    }
});
```

Actually I've gotten the code inside the comments to work (instead of the line `new FusionCharts(chartConfig).render();`) but note its reliance on `eval()`.  Is there a way to avoid this?  It was the only thing I could think of given the need to reference the `FusionChart` instances by both the reference/variable name, and the need to additionally use it as the `id` property in the configuration sent to `configureLink`

Comment: Are you sure that the `id` needs to refer to a (global) variable name? Have you tried your code with just `var fChart = new FusionCharts(chartConfig);` (no `eval`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that `id` attribute inside the `configureLink` method is that important. Please refer to this [document](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#configureLink]).

The code should work fine this way

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var fusionChartsCfg = JSON.parse(chartJson); //chartJson defined above

    for (var i=0, n=fusionChartsCfg.length; i<n; i++) {
        var chartConfig = fusionChartsCfg[i];
        new FusionCharts(chartConfig).render().configureLink({
                type: chartConfig.linkedChartType
            });         
    }
});
```